# WordPress, front-page.php in BlankSlate

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to directly code front-page.php in the WordPress BlankSlate theme. There is no front-page.php supplied with this theme, but I was startled to discover that when I created front-page.php it started using it. There must be some code somewhere that checks for front-page.php. Anyway, now I need to know the basic structure of front-page.php. Can I get something like an example that contains the header, proper div classes for the main content, and footer?

What I have now is the following. This is leftover from when I was using the Roots theme.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
       <img class="frontpageimg" src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/slogan-2.jpg">


       <h4>In the Los Angeles area? </h4> <p>Ask about free demo loaners! </p>
       <h4>We also take mail orders.</h4> On all orders, there is a 30-day return policy!</p> 



       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/cables-ers-absorber-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/blueprint-silencers-v2-700.jpg"/></a>
       <img src = "<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/brav-front-page-700.jpg"/></a>

        <a href="contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-orange">Contact Us</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the boilerplate wrapper code that you could enter your content into:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" role="main">

</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'd take a look at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display) page on the WordPress Codex to help you get a better idea of what the front-page template is used for.